# Does the Power Apps with SQL Connector will use Connection Reference while connecting to SQL Database/Table in Canvas App?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, sql, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have a canvas app using SQL as data source connector, currently I am using connection.

But while moving from one environment to another as a managed solution I am unable to change the SQL connection in the power apps as environment variables are not being supported here in this case.

So my doubt is solution I am having consists of Connection Reference, can this be used by Power Apps while connecting to the database?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

If you are using a Power Platform solution with connection reference, Canvas Power Apps supports using the connection reference for SQL connector.

We are using connection references with SQL connector in many of our canvas apps. And while moving solution from development environment to QA or production environment, it asks for selecting connection from QA/production to associate with used connection reference.

**Documentations**:

1. [Use a connection reference in a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-connection-reference?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [SQL server connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/sql?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Connect to SQL Server from Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: How to change the SQL Database and Server Name in the power app when we change from Dev to UAT to Prod environments where SQL servers and databases are different for dev uat and prod

Comment: You have to create SQL connection in all the environments first --> each environment can have the SQL connector with different server & DB names. While deploying managed solution in QA/PROD environment, you can select respective connection for your connection reference.